# Android equivalent of NSUserDefaults in iOS

Tags: android, ios, nsuserdefaults, code-translation

I'd like to save some simple data. On the iPhone, I can do it with [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsuserdefaults?language=objc) in Objective-C.

What is the similar command here in Android?

I'm just saving a few variables, to be reused as long as the application is installed. I don't want to use a complicated database just to do that.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

This is the most simple solution I've found:

```
//--Init
int myvar = 12;


//--SAVE Data
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("var1", myvar);
editor.apply();


//--READ data       
myvar = preferences.getInt("var1", 0);
```

Where 'context' is the current context (e.g. in an activity subclass could be *this*).

Comment: this is the way to go for storing very simple things, its simple and straight to the point

Comment: I fixed the error in the code (was calling the non-existent getPreferences, not getSharedPreferences).

Comment: Update 2015: Android recommends the use of apply() now over commit() because apply() operates on a background thread instead of storing the persistent data immediately and possible blocking the main thread.

Comment: Is there a way to access this SharedPreferences from jni code?

Comment: To get the 'context' from within  `AppCompatActivity`, you can use `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: An Activity *is* your context. So use 'this' as context in Activities. In Fragments you'll want to use requireActivity().