# Store value using system preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to store some variables using system preferences.I tried some tutorials, but the application keeps on crashing.Can someone help me out.I also tried according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584267/android-similar-nsuserdefaults-from-iphone).Also this code :

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

This is the logcat output:

```
06-03 15:17:08.600: D/BstCommandProcessor-Application(908): Application crash has been observed. 
06-03 15:17:08.600: I/Process(10216): Sending signal. PID: 10216 SIG: 9
06-03 15:17:08.600: D/AndroidRuntime(10216): procName from cmdline: com.example.flash4
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.flash4
06-03 15:17:08.600: D/AndroidRuntime(10216): file written successfully with content: com.example.flash4 StringBuffer : ;com.example.flash4
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flash4/com.example.flash4.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:371)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:366)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at com.example.flash4.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:71)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1025)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
06-03 15:17:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(10216):    ... 11 more
06-03 15:17:08.690: I/ActivityManager(610): Process com.example.flash4 (pid 10216) has died.
06-03 15:17:08.690: W/ActivityManager(610): Force removing ActivityRecord{b335c7d8 com.example.flash4/.MainActivity}: app died, no saved state
```

Comment: Which code do you need.Error came at line 71 ie,the code that i gave above.

Comment: try this  `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` in your `Activity`

Comment: have You renamed anything in Your project? IF yes, be sure You have no errors inside ande clean project

Comment: @Simple Plan:that line is giving me this error : The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity) is undefined for the type MainActivity

Comment: Make sure the context you give is valid. In order to get the default SharedPreferences you need to have an context. This is required because getDefaultSharedPreferences() will call getSharedPreferences(String name, mode), where "name" is gotten like this, context.getPackageName() + "_preferences";
You can also make your custom file, like:
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("sp_file_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: Thanks.it worked.I gave the code inside the onCreate() and it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

Instead of:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

**EDIT**

If you are not already doing this, place the above code in the `onCreate()` method. If you want the preferences to be available elsewhere, do

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

so that it gets declared as global, then do this in `onCreate()`

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

Answer (score 2):

As Simple you can use this.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyKey",0);
Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

and when you want to retrieve then you use this wherever you want in your app

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyKey",0);
```