# Java Swing NSUserDefaults analog

Tags: java, registry, nsuserdefaults, persist

Is there any possibility to persist some (string) value to system that will be available in Java application from run to run like persisting to [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) in Objective-C?

Solving this problem in Android: [Android equivalent of NSUserDefaults in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584267/android-similar-nsuserdefaults-from-iphone)

Comment: See [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).

Comment: Yes - There are __tons__ of persistence methods for plain Java apps - [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) is one, or write to a database or text file or even store it in some cloud service. You have so many choices - just pick one that works for your use case.